# didReceive response with completionHandler not getting Called in Service extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just added extensions for rich push, in that I implemented a delegate method for customisation.
`func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) { }`. But this method didn't get called. Also my extensions deployment target is 10. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am getting image, gif,audio but video is getting displayed after expansion.

Comment: In local notification, video is working fine. But same video not working in remote notifications.

Comment: You can't add logs in Extension, they won't get printed in console. For debugging Use pid. Debug-> Attach to process by pid. Make sure you are adding "content-available":1, in your payload. Refer this if needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/50903844/5084797

Comment: @ManishKumar Thanks for response...Its working fine but while playing audio or video, the sound is very low even after increasing it to max. But same files if I use in local notifications, the sound is good.

Comment: Try with some other URL's, I have never faced such issues.

Comment: @ManishKumar let me check...