# Notification service extension payload to send image, contact and location

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, silent-notification

I had developed a notification service extension to send message notification with silent notification.Now i want to send image,Contact and location with message.Is that possible to send this data to thorugh notification service extension.
Thanks in advance.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Contact and location will not be possible. For image/video/gif/audio refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50903844/5084797

Comment: Welcome! I suggest checking the developer documentation and wwdc sessions about notifications. Feel free to ask if you have specific questions or problems

Comment: how did you manage to make it silent , what payload you sent , as my case is that notification is always showned