# How to send a promotional image in the push notification in MFP

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

How to send the promotional image in the push notification as it is like the below image? Do I need to use any html code in payload? If possible kindly share the code snippet.

[image: like this].

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50523908/5084797

Answer (score 0):

Edit April 2019:

IBM MobileFirst 8.0 supports sending rich push notifications. Update to the latest server and client side fix packs to get the feature. Use the following payload structure when dispatching Push:

Push payload:

```
{  
   "message":{  
      "alert":"Picture Notification for Android devices ",
      "url":"http://www.test.com"
   },
   "target":{  
      "deviceIds": ["MyDeviceId1", ...],
      "platforms": ["A,G", ...],
      "tagNames": ["Gold", ...],
      "userIds": ["MyUserId", ...]
   },
   "settings":{  
      "gcm":{  
         "style":{  
            "notification_type":"PICTURE_NOTIFICATION",
            "url":"<URL of the image that needs to be displayed>",
            "title":"Test"
         },
      "apns": {
         "attachmentUrl" : "http://test.com/test.png",
         "badge" : 1,
         "category" : 1,
         "iosActionKey" : "Ok",
         "launchImage" : "test.png",
         "locArgs" : [ "["Shelly"]", ... ],
         "locKey" : "REQ_FORMAT",
         "payload" : {"custom":"data"},
         "sound" : "song.mp3",
         "subtitle" : "Sub Title",
         "title" : "Title",
         "titleLocArgs" : [ "["Shelly"]", ... ],
         "titleLocKey" : "REQ_FORMAT",
         "type" : "SILENT"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: your answer is confusing bro, kindly elaborate