# APNS with image and cutomised view

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have to integrate APNS in my app. But, its data is not just textual and sent from the server. I have to interpret the data sent in the payload and display it according to the design being given to me. It includes an image too (screenshot attached). Do I have to create an APNS extention for this or it can be handled by some other means? I am using UserNotifications.h and its delegates (willPresentNotification, didReceiveNotificationResponse). It does not have any user interactions like button clicks etc, just clicking on the notification anywhere would navigate the user inside the app. Please help.

[image]

Comment: useful stuff: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/817/

Answer (score 0):

For getting Image with notification you can follow [This for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50903844/5084797) or [This for ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50523908/5084797) .

For Custom UI. You need to add "Notification Content Extension" into your app, there you will get a Storyboard which you can customise according to your design or needs. For customisation you can use [this](https://www.appcoda.com/user-notifications-ios12/) tutorial.